# Triggering onContentPrepare from Category Blog view

Tags: plugin, com-content, custom-field

I found this page on how to implement a custom field in article:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component

and it works well, but only in `article` view.

What should I do else, to make it show that custom field in each article, when in `category blog` view?

I tried adding :

```
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content', 'plg_content_rating');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array('com_content.category', & $this->item, &$this->item->params, 0));
```

to my `category blog` override file, but that didn't work.

Also in `components/com_content/views/category/view.html.php` file,
there is a line like this:

```
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.category', &$item, &$this->params, 0));
```

Shouldn't that already trigger all registered content plugins?

The similar line in `article's` *view.html.php* file, works well for that
purpose.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display your custom field in the introtext?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your intention.

If you use onContentPrepare to manipulate the markup you need to use the right scope. Your MyPlugin::onContentPrepare will always been fired if the plugin is loaded and a dispatcher triggers "onContentPrepare".

But usually you will check against the scope like

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
{
    if (in_array($context, array('com_content.article'))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So make sure you use the right scopes.

If you just want to display the custom data within an overwrite, you can simply 
access it with $item.